# std::string implementation in GCC and its memory overhead for short strings

Tags: c++, string, compiler-construction, memory-management

I am currently working on an application for a low-memory platform that requires an std::set of many short strings (>100,000 strings of 4-16 characters each). I recently transitioned this set from std::string to const char * to save memory and I was wondering whether I was really avoiding all that much overhead per string.

I tried using the following:

```
std::string sizeTest = "testString";
std::cout << sizeof(sizeTest) << " bytes";
```

But it just gave me an output of 4 bytes, indicating that the string contains a pointer. I'm well aware that strings store their data in a char * internally, but I thought the string class would have additional overhead.

Does the GCC implementation of std::string incur more overhead than sizeof(std::string) would indicate? More importantly, is it significant over this size of data set?

Here are the sizes of relevant types on my platform (it is 32-bit and has 8 bits per byte):

char: 1 bytes
void *: 4 bytes
char *: 4 bytes
std::string: 4 bytes

Comment: On what platform do you get this result? I ask because I've seen platforms (Texas Instruments DSPs) where a byte is considered to be 16-bits.

Comment: What is the result of `sizeof(char*)` on your platform?

Comment: I'm guessing that `std::string` contains a pointer to a dynamically-allocated string implementation object. Keep in mind that GCC's string are COW (copy on write). I've tried looking at gcc's `basic_string.h` for some insights, but got a headache trying to read the cryptic code.

Comment: @Emile Cormier: Number of bits in a byte is defined by CHAR_BITS

Comment: Are the string Imutable? If so then you may save space. But if they need to be manipulated then it is unlikely that you will save anything because of the extra complexity you introduce.

Comment: I don't think `std::string` is the same size as `char*` for any implementation I've ever seen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, at least with GCC 4.4.5, which is what I have handy on this
machine, `std::string` is a typdef for `std::basic_string<char>`, and
`basic_string` is defined in
`/usr/include/c++/4.4.5/bits/basic_string.h`. There's a lot of
indirection in that file, but what it comes down to is that nonempty
`std::string`s store a pointer to one of these:

```
  struct _Rep_base
  {
size_type       _M_length;
size_type       _M_capacity;
_Atomic_word        _M_refcount;
  };
```

Followed in-memory by the actual string data. So `std::string` is
going to have at least three words of overhead for each string, plus
any overhead for having a higher `capacity` than `` `length `` (probably
not, depending on how you construct your strings -- you can check by
asking the `capacity()` method).

There's also going to be overhead from your memory allocator for doing
lots of small allocations; I don't know what GCC uses for C++, but
assuming it's similar to the `dlmalloc` allocator it uses for C, that
could be at least two words per allocation, plus some space to align
the size to a multiple of at least 8 bytes.

Comment: Many implementations use the Small Buffer Optimization to not do allocations for strings less than 3-7ish characters, does GCC not do this?

Comment: I just checked microsoft's implementation, which allows strings of up to 15 `char`s (plus NULL) with no allocation.

Comment: gcc uses cow string that is nonconforming.. they will switch to sso when they can do a breaking abi change... Herb mentions it often...

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to guess you are on a 32 bit, 8 bit per byte platform.  I'm also going to guess that at least on the gcc version you are using, that they are using a reference counted implementation for std::string.  The 4 byte sizeof you see is a pointer to a structure containing the reference count and the string data (and any allocator state if applicable).

In this design of gcc's the only "short" string has size == 0, in which case it can share a representation with every other empty string.  Otherwise you get a refcounted COW string.

To investigate this yourself, code up an allocator that keeps track of how much memory it allocates and deallocates, and how many times.  Use this allocator to investigate the implementation of the container you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

If it's guaranteed that ">100,000 strings of 4-16 characters each", then don't use std::string. Instead, write your own ShortString class. It's interesting that "sizeof(std::string) == 4", how is that possible? What are sizeof(char) and sizeof(void *)?

Comment: It's always *possible*. It could just hold a pointer to some kind of internal string structure, which holds all the usual data, like length and pointer to the string data.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: @jalf If it just holds a pointer to an internal structure, then the actual memory cost is added by sizeof(void *) when the string is longer than sizeof(void *)-1. I could imagine some size optimization based on the pointer encoding is done for std::string when the size is small.

Comment: @albert: I don't understand what you mean. But to get `sizeof(std::string) == 4`, you just need to be on a 32-bit system (where pointers are 4 bytes wide), and then store a single pointer, and no other members inside the string class. That pointer can just refer to a secondary data structure containing length/capacity and a pointer to the actual string buffer